# Send Ctrl-A and Ctrl-D from shellscript to a GNU screen

Tags: bash, signals, send, gnu-screen

How can I send the signals of CTRL-A and CTRL-D from a shell script to a screen? 
Next code doesnt work to me. Screen process still is running in foreground and I want that it executes in background. Any idea?

```
#!/bin/sh
#TweetBot notifications with Growl

cd ~/node-tweetbot/
screen -S "tweet" node app.js -X stuff "'^A' '^D'"
```

Comment: Is this what you are looking for: _" -d -m   Start screen in "detached" mode. This creates a new session but doesn't attach to it. This is useful for system startup scripts."_

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could simply start up `screen` in detached mode.  From the man page:

```
   -d -m   Start screen in "detached" mode. This creates a new session but
           doesn't  attach  to  it.  This  is  useful  for  system startup
           scripts.
```

So this:

```
screen -S tweet -d -m node app.js
```

Would start up your screen session detached.  You could attach to it at a later time by running:

```
screen -x tweet
```